# How to fix a messy .zshrc file after trying to add homebrew to the correct path on macbook pro m1?

Tags: installation, homebrew, zsh

I’ve tried any method I managed to find online a dozen of times but none of them work, I keep on getting the same:

`zsh: command not found: brew`

error after opening a new terminal window. At some point I managed to at least access brew using the command:

`source ~/.bash_profile`,

but currently for some reason such line of code pops up at the beginning of each new terminal window:

```
/Users/ahryncyszyn/.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context:
Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

and even this method doesn't work anymore.

I think it might have something to do with my .zshrc file - after trying repeatedly multiple methods to add homebrew to the correct path, I have multiple clearly redundant lines of code there:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ahryncyszyn/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/$USER/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ahryncyszyn/Library/Application
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could provide clarification regarding which lines should be retained. As far as I understand, incorrect paths in this file might be the reason for the error in the terminal window, so maybe fixing it would help to finally access homebrew properly.

Comment: any `PATH=` that doesn't end with `:$PATH` should be investigated. I see 2 of them, try commenting those out or adding `:$PATH` to the end of them. `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)` looks very suspicious too, if you're not sure what that's doing then don't do it as `eval` can be dangerous.

Comment: Don't try to source bash-specific shell files from zsh or vis versa; that will never work well.

Comment: Manipulating the `path` *array* variable is usually a better choice in zsh than working with `PATH`; the two are linked together so changes to one are reflected in the other.

Comment: @EdMorton as soon as I commented the first export line out the error message disappeared and now it detects brew!! However, when I type 'where brew' it gives me three times the same directory, I guess that might be because I exported the path multiple times, right? Can it produce any problems in the future? I tried to detect the duplicates in the file, but I managed to decrease their number only for conda, not brew

Comment: @Shawn how do you access the `path` array?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with exporting the PATH, it's because you keep appending the same paths to PATH. You do `PATH=foo:$PATH` then `PATH=bar:$PATH` then `PATH=foo:$PATH` again so `foo` appears multiple times in your PATH so then when you do `where -a brew` (which I assume is what you're using) it tells you every directory in your PATH that contains it so if it's under `foo` that'll be printed twice. I see at least 3 lines in your script where you do `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` - don't do that, just add each path to PATH one time.

Comment: Like any other array variable

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, finding 20 different "solutions" online to add a path for *Homebrew*, but ultimately they all threw errors/warnings or failed to persist in new Terminal sessions.

Finally, I resolved it by manually adding *only* the following two lines of code to my **.zshrc** file:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```

**.zshrc** is a hidden file located in your Home directory aka `/Users/$HOME`. To view hidden files, open your Home folder and press `Command + Shift + .` Then open the **.zshrc** file in your text editor, add the two lines shared above, then save this file. Lastly, close then reopen Terminal to reinitialize it. You should now be able to run `brew doctor` and hopefully see `Your system is ready to brew.`

Note that your **.zshrc** file may contain code for things other than just *Homebrew*, so you'll want to leave those lines alone. Only delete the code pertaining to `/opt/homebrew` and replace it with the two lines above. For reference, here's my **.zshrc** file in it's entirety, which includes the three lines needed to resolve the equally frustrating `zsh: command not found: nvm` error:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
```